# Kivy center content Python GridLayout/FloatLayout

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, centering

So I am trying to center all my contents (image and buttons) in my kv file

Here some KV code that i want to modify. I tried FloatLayout being parent of Grid one, not worked. Anchor tried too.

```
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                BoxLayout:
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    spacing: 10



                    Image:
                        source: "./icons/quietKid_.png"
                        size_hint: None, None
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}



                    BoxLayout:
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                        orientation: 'horizontal'
                        width: self.minimum_width
                        height: self.minimum_height



                        canvas:
                            Color:
                                rgba: get_color_from_hex("#171717")
                            RoundedRectangle:
                                size: self.size
                                pos: self.pos



                        width: self.minimum_width
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        size_hint_x: None
                        size_hint_y: None


                        
                        ButtonHover:
                            text:'Profil'
                            background_color: (0,0,0,0)
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size_hint_x: None
                            size: 80, 50
                            canvas.after:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: (self.pos[0] + 5, self.pos[1])
                                    size: (self.wysokosc, 1)



                        ButtonHover:
                            text:'Discord'
                            background_color: (0,0,0,0)
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size_hint_x: None
                            size: 80, 50
                            canvas.after:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: (self.pos[0] + 5, self.pos[1])
                                    size: (self.wysokosc, 1)


                                    
                        ButtonHover:
                            text:'NameMC'
                            background_color: (0,0,0,0)
                            size_hint_x: None
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size: 80, 50
                            canvas.after:
                                Color:
                                    rgba: get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
                                Rectangle:
                                    pos: (self.pos[0] + 0, self.pos[1])
                                    size: (self.wysokosc, 1)
```

[Buttons and Image not centered on Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYzyu.png)

Wanted it to center on both X and Y, but i dont just know how, maybe something conflicts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Note that according to the [BoxLayout documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.1.0/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html), concerning `pos_hint`:

> If the orientation is vertical: x, right and center_x will be used.

So, `center_y` will have no effect inside your `BoxLayout` that has `vertical` orientation.

You can get the widgets centered vertically by adding `Widgets` to the top and bottom of the `BoxLayout`, like this:

```
            BoxLayout:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: 10

                Widget:

                # your stuff to be centered

                Widget:
```

This works because the added `Widgets` have the default `size_hint_y` of 1.0. The `BoxLayout` assigns its available vertical space by assigning the specified space for children that have a specified `height` (your `Image` and horizontal `BoxLayout`) and sharing the remaining space according to `size_hint_y`. So the remaining space (after the `Image` and `BoxLayout` get theirs) is divided equally between the two `Widgets`.